# pyinstaller - 'No module named...' error with scripts import

Tags: python, module, pyinstaller, git-submodules

I need to compile my Python 3.10 project to an executable via **pyinstaller** and can't seem to get my imports working when executing the exe file.

My "test" project structure looks like this

```
src/
__init__.py
app/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    main.spec
    version.rc
lib/
    core/
        __init__.py
        core_test.py
    service/
        __init__.py
        service_test.py
    __init__.py
```

In this example I'm building the **main.exe** file which contains this code:

```
from src.lib.service import service_tst
from src.lib.core import core_tst

service_tst.do_something()
core_tst.do_something()
```

My **spec** file look like this:

```
block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
         pathex=[],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         hooksconfig={},
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts, 
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      [],
      name='main',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      upx_exclude=[],
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=True,
      disable_windowed_traceback=False,
      target_arch=None,
      codesign_identity=None,
      entitlements_file=None,
      icon='',
      version='version.rc')
```

So far, so good.

Now, after creating the exe file with pyinstaller, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

### Here's what I did so far:

Adding **"src"** to **hiddenimports**

```
hiddenimports=["src"]
```

gives me the following **error**:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.lib'
```

When I add both, **src** and **src.lib**

```
hiddenimports=["src", "src.lib"],
```

I still get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.lib'
```

When I use **collect_submodules** like this:

```
src_hidden_import = collect_submodules('src')
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
         pathex=[],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=src_hidden_import,
         ...
```

i get the following **error**:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.lib'
```

The "real" project obviously contains a lot of imports, all starting with src., so I'll need pyinstaller to crawl my whole project/file structure and pack all used scripts into the executable.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what is in the `app/__init__.py`?

Comment: The __init__.py are all empty. Just to mark modules

Answer (score 0):

According to the [pyinstaller documentation](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-p) you can use the option `-p DIR` or `--paths DIR` to define additional paths to search for imports:

> -p DIR, --paths DIR:
> A path to search for imports (like using PYTHONPATH). Multiple paths are allowed, separated by ':', or use this option multiple times. Equivalent to supplying the pathex argument in the spec file.

Try adding your project path to `pathex` in your specfile. Your can do this via a normal (relative or absolute) path (i.e. `pathex=["<your-project-path>"]` or `pathex=["."]`) or via the [Globals Available to the Spec File](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#globals-available-to-the-spec-file) (i.e. `pathex=[SPECPATH]` which points to the location of your specfile).

Then pyinstaller will search in these additional location(s) for your imports and modules.

Here is an example of your specfile where I added `SPECPATH` to the `pathex`:

```
block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
         pathex=[SPECPATH],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         hooksconfig={},
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
```